# How to create a Wordpress shortcode-style function in PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

I am trying to create a Wordpress shortcode-style feature in PHP to replace shortcodes like "[[133]]" with images. Basically, I have a MySQL table of image URLs/titles/subtitles with IDs 1-150, and I want to be able to dynamically insert them into the text of my pages with shortcodes like this:

**Blabla bla bla bla bla. [[5]] Also, bla bla bla bla bla [[27]] 
Hey, and bla bla bla! [[129]]**

So, I just want to grab the ID as $id, and then feed it to a MySQL query like
mysql_query("SELECT title,subtitle,url FROM images WHERE id = $id")
and then replace the "[[id]]" with the img/title/subtitle. I would like to be able to do this multiple times on the same page.

I know this has to involve regex and some combination of preg_match, preg_replace, strstr, strpos, substr... but I don't know where to start and which functions I should be using to do which things. Can you recommend a strategy?  I don't need the code itself—just knowing what to use for which parts would be extremely helpful.

Comment: Note - this is NOT for a Wordpress site, so I can't use existing WP shortcode functions.

Comment: Maybe this also involves preg_replace_callback?

Comment: I would venture a guess and say that you could probably extract the related code out of WordPress easily enough. Alternatively, you can just do what Kyle suggested and use one of many approaches to create your own solution.

Comment: With a function getimage($id) that does the MySQL query, this *almost* does everything I need: [not enough space—see answer]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With a function `getimage($id)` that does the MySQL query and formats the replacement text, this *almost* does everything you need:

```
$text = "Blabla [[5]] and [[111]] bla bla bla [[27]] and bla bla bla! [[129]]";

$zpreg = preg_match_all('#\[\[(\d{1,3})\]\]#', $text, $matches );

var_dump( $matches[1] );  

$newtext = preg_replace('#\[\[(\d{1,3})\]\]#', getimage($matches[1][?????]), $text);

echo $newtext;
```

I just need to figure out what to put inside `getimage()` (where ????? is) that will make it put in the right image for the right `[[id]]`.

Refer [**`preg_match_all`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) and [**`preg_replace`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) on official documentation for more details.

Answer (score 9):

If you want to be able to write shortcodes like this :

```
[[function_name_suffix parameter1 parameter2 ...]]
```

here is a more complete way, using `preg_replace_callback` and `call_user_func_array` to implement parameterized shortcodes.

```
function shortcodify($string){
    return preg_replace_callback('#\[\[(.*?)\]\]#', function ($matches) {
        $whitespace_explode = explode(" ", $matches[1]);
        $fnName = 'shortcode_'.array_shift($whitespace_explode);
        return function_exists($fnName) ? call_user_func_array($fnName,$whitespace_explode) : $matches[0];
    }, $string);
}
```

If this function is defined :

```
function shortcode_name($firstname="",$lastname=""){
    return "<span class='firstname'>".$firstname."</span>&nbsp;<span class='lastname'>".$lastname."</span>";
}
```

Then this call

```
print shortcodify("My name is [[name armel larcier]]");
```

Will output :

```
My name is <span class='firstname'>armel</span>&nbsp;<span class='lastname'>larcier</span>
```

This is just something I implemented right now based on supertrue's idea.

Any feedback is more than welcome.

Comment: Oh ok, I thought that this works in PHP 5.4+ because you code didn't work at first attempt. Then I found out that you have a typo in your function name. You call a function shortcodify() but it's definded as shortcodifiy() - the "i" makes the difference. I corrected this for you.

Comment: Nice catch. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Various different approaches can be taken for this, depending on how you plan to display ect,

Take the sentence "Hello [34] world"

Create a simple function e.g replaceCode($string)

```
function replaceCode($string){

    $pos = strpos($string, '['); // Find the first occurrence of the bracket

    if($pos != false){

          // If everything is ok take the next 2 numbers from it

          // Check for a close bracket & remove ]

          // call another function to replace the number with the image text

    }




}
```

If anymore occurrences of brackets are found, recursively call the function again, passing the rest of the string to the function again.

Note: Validation may need to be done first to ensure the [ and ] are properly balanced!

Answer (score 0):

The regex, I believe, would be:

```
/\[\[[1-9]{1,3}\]\]/g
```

(for a 1-to-3 digit number inside double brackets.)

Answer (score 0):

My bet is [PHP's strtr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtr.php) function...

```
<?php
function get_profile_image($image_url){
    return "<img src='{$image_url}' height='200px' width='200px' />";
}

$trans = array(
    "[[1]]" => "Vishal",
    "[[2]]" => "Kumar",
    "[[3]]" => "Sahu",
    "[[4]]" => "Web Designer",
    "[[5]]" => "Draw and Paint",
    "[[6]]" => ucwords("any programming language"),
    "[[7]]" => strtoupper("PHP, JAVASCRIPT and HTML"),
    "[[8]]" => get_profile_image("http://php.net/images/logos/php-logo.svg"),
    "[[9]]" => "http://php.net/images/logos/php-logo.svg"
    );
$str = <<<HEREDOC_1
[[8]]
<pre>My name is [[1]] [[2]] [[3]].
I am a [[4]] and I love to [[5]].
I don't know [[6]] but I know [[7]] little bit.</pre>
Here is my profile image <img src='[[9]]' alt='[[1]]-[[2]]-[[3]]-[[4]]' />
HEREDOC_1;
echo strtr($str, $trans);
```

it's output is

> [http://php.net/images/logos/php-logo.svg] My name is Vishal Kumar
>   Sahu. I am a Web Designer and I love to Draw and Paint. I don't know
>   Any Programming Language but I know PHP, JAVASCRIPT AND HTML little
>   bit. Here is my profile image [Vishal-Kumar-Sahu-Web Designer]

It is working fine on 5.6.

Comment: The PHP documentation page should not change. I will add it @MegaTron :D