# PHP regex replace between wordpress shortcode tag

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have a shortcode which I want to be able to strip away depending on the context of the post. Eg.

```
[tooltip slug="test"]Test Text[/tooltip]
```

I would like the output to be:

```
<span class="dummy">Test Text</span>
```

I have experimented (a lot!) with preg_replace and I can't seem to get it to recognize that the replacement string is between the ']'  and then delimited by '[/tooltip]' without doing multiple passes.

Ideas?

Update: As so often happens, about 10 seconds after I wrote this one of my attempts seemed to work. I don't think it's as good as the solution below but FWIW...

```
$my_var .= preg_replace('/(?:\[tooltip slug=\"([^\"]*)"[^\>]*\]([^\<]*)\[\/tooltip\])/', '<span class="dummy">\\2</span>', $my_post->post_content);
```

Comment: Please show your attempt(s), that way we could improve your mistakes. Btw, I'm pretty sure this has been asked before

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create a Wordpress shortcode-style function in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4568463/how-to-create-a-wordpress-shortcode-style-function-in-php)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the simple regex you are looking for.

```
$result = preg_replace('%\[tooltip slug="[^"]*"]([^[]*)\[/tooltip]%',
          '<span class="dummy">\1</span>', $subject);
```

What we do here is capture the text between the tooltip tags, and insert it in the replacement.
Let me know if you need any details.

Comment: Thanks. I struggled with the bracket after 'slug='['. I could only seem to get it to work as -two- expressions. Obviously I wasn't patient enough in walking it through.

Comment: @jchwebdev As you can see there's not a lot of escaping that needs to be done. Once you're comfortable with what needs and doesn't need escaping, your expressions are a lot cleaner. I recommend not using slash (/) as a delimiter, use % or ~ or # depending on the situation. Too many slashes in html: it ends up looking like soup. It's great that you're using NOT (^) in your character classes. You're on your way with regex. :) At this stage you may benefit from "The Elements of Regex Style" article. http://www.rexegg.com/regex-style.html

Comment: Wow. That is a -great- tutorial. I've looked at many and for some reason this thing just clicked. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
$test = preg_match('/\[([^\]]+)\]([^\[]+)\[/', '[tooltip slug="test"]Test Text[/tooltip]', $matches);

echo $matches[2];
```