# wordpress style shortcodes in Ckeditor / PHP

Tags: php, mysql, function, ckeditor

I have built a custom CMS. Recently, I added the ability to create pages dynamically. I used CKEditor for the content of these pages.
I would also like to run some php functions that may be included in the content of the page stored in mysql. 
I DO NOT want to store actual PHP code in the database, but rather function names perhaps. For example, in a page stored in the database I may have.

```
<?php //begin output
hello world!
check out this latest news article.
news($type, $id);
//end output 
?>
```

What is the best way to find and execute this existing function without using EVAL if its found in the output? I was thinking along the lines of wordpress style short codes. Maybe [[news(latest, 71]] ? Then have a function to find and execute these functions if they exist in my functions.php file. Not really sure the best way to go about this.
I'm not searching for any code answers, but more of a best practice for this type of scenario, especially one that is safest against possible injections.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution from digging around and finding this thread
[How to create a Wordpress shortcode-style function in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4568463/how-to-create-a-wordpress-shortcode-style-function-in-php)

I am able to pass short codes like this in CKEditor

```
[[utube 1 video_id]]
```

Then, in my page that renders the code:

```
print shortcodify($page_content);
```

using this function:

```
function shortcodify($string){
    return preg_replace_callback('#\[\[(.*?)\]\]#', function ($matches) {
    $whitespace_explode = explode(" ", $matches[1]);
    $fnName = array_shift($whitespace_explode);
    return function_exists($fnName) ? call_user_func_array($fnName,$whitespace_explode) : $matches[0];
    }, $string);
    }
```

If the function name exist (utube) it will fire the function.
Only problem Im having at the moment is not matter where I place the [[shortcode]] in my editor, it always executes first. 
For example, in CKEditor I put:

```
Hello world! Check out my latest video
[[utube 1 video_id]]
```

It will always put the text under the video instead of where it is in the document. I need to figure a way to have the short code execute in the order it is placed.